# play/pause gif with mouse event

Tags: javascript, html, gif, animated-gif

I have an image format gif, in my web page.

I want to go with the mouse on any image to run animations. And as long as the mouse is still there, it stays on the last frame and When the mouse stepped back into the original image.

can someone help?

Comment: not sure you can achieve that with classic gifs... html5 video if your browser support allows you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like that:

HTML

```
<div id="images">
    <div class="img img1">
        <img data-gif_src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mdnaeqwmTr1rtuulro1_250.gif" src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2011/12/25/article-2078552-0F44CB3D00000578-206_468x331.jpg"/>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#images .img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;    
}

#images .img img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;    
}
```

JS

```
$('#images .img img').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).data('img_src', $(this).attr('src') );
    $(this).attr('src',  $(this).data('gif_src') );  
}).mouseleave( function(){
    $(this).attr('src',  $(this).data('img_src') ); 
});
```

[on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh6uat9j/)

Comment: You can choose between a plain javascript library or a jquery plugin